# No alert "Untrusted App Developer" and no "Profiles" in settings

Tags: ios, provisioning-profile

Before iOS 9, I remember being asked about "do you trust the developer..." the first time I ran my app tests on a specific device.

After iOS 9, I read that trusted developers should appear under "General" -> "Settings" -> "Profiles" (and they must be manually trusted).

(I have an active developer account)

I have no such thing under Settings, and I'm never asked about "Untrusted App Developer" when I run my tests now, even after a full device restore. And every app I build under XCode just installs without asking to trust any developer (I repeat, I already tried a full device reset).

How do I check "trusted" developers with iOS 9? How do I know if I have been trusted on a device if nothing appears? (I know, of course, that if an app runs I have been granted trusted privileges, but I'd like to see them somewhere)

Anyone else having the same issues?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Trust action needed only when it comes to:

- Enterprise certificates

See
[Apple Docs](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT204460)

Comment: Thank you very much. But do I remember it wrong or did they use to ask (before ios 9) to trust developers the first time an application was run (outside of app store), even if it used a development certificate?

Comment: @JohnRambo Not that I remember such a thing. I've always seen it when I used enterprise. Before iOS 9.0 it would give you the options to select "trust" on the alert itself. However, from iOS 9.0 as you understood, you need to go into settings and verify it manually.